# Large data sets with array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, large-data

Currently I have large data sets ( 2 columns which are X and Y and more than 2000 arrows) in excel and csv. files which I want to import and use in Python as array list of values in X and Y. I can't seem to import this X and Y columns with around 2000 values into the code in order to work with them and test my code instead of the small number values that I input manually in the code below.

What kind of package am I supposed to use?
Thanks

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

import scipy.integrate as integrate

# limit axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

# fraction of total flow capacity
Y = np.array([0.172, 0.33, 0.481, 0.604, 0.683, 0.747, 0.801, 0.831, 0.855, 0.876, 0.892, 0.906, 0.918, 0.93, 0.939, 0.947,
     0.954, 0.96, 0.965, 0.969, 0.973, 0.976, 0.979, 0.983, 0.986, 0.988, 0.99, 0.992, 0.995, 0.996, 0.998, 0.999, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# fraction of total volume
X = np.array([0.042, 0.083, 0.123, 0.162, 0.2, 0.236, 0.273, 0.303, 0.337, 0.37, 0.403, 0.425, 0.448, 0.477, 0.504, 0.528, 0.553,
     0.577, 0.599, 0.621, 0.645, 0.667, 0.689, 0.711, 0.733, 0.753, 0.774, 0.796, 0.818, 0.838, 0.859, 0.878, 0.898,
     0.914, 0.933, 0.945, 0.96, 0.977, 0.993, 1])

plt.plot(X, Y, 'bo')
plt.title('Lorenz Plot')
plt.ylabel('Flow Capacity, F')
plt.xlabel('Storage Capacity, C')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# equality line
y_eq = x
plt.plot(x, y_eq, 'g')

# building Lorenz curve

# transforming the data to include another axis
x = X[:, np.newaxis]
y = Y[:, np.newaxis]

polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
x_poly = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_poly, y)
y_poly_pred = model.predict(x_poly)

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_poly_pred))
r2 = r2_score(y, y_poly_pred)
print("RMSE = ", rmse)
print('R^2 = ', r2)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
plt.plot(x, y_poly_pred, color='m')


# function as argument to scipy integrate.quad using coef_ method
def f(x):
    i = len(model.coef_[0]) - 1
    eq = 0
    while (i > 0):
        eq += model.coef_[0][i] * x ** i
        i = i - 1
    eq = eq + model.intercept_[0]
    eq = eq - x
    return eq


# calculate area ABCA, area ADCA = 0.5
result = integrate.quad(lambda x: f(x), 0, 1)
print("The result of integral:", result[0])
print("Lorenz coefficient = ", round(result[0] / 0.5, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

To read your csv and excel file you can use Pandas. It will give you a DataFrame which you can easily turn it into a list with some operations.

```
import pandas as pd

# To make operations for excel files also import
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

#Reading csv
xFile = pd.read_csv('#PathofCSVfile.csv')

#Reading excel
yFile = pd.read_excel('#PathofCSVfile.xlsx', sheetname='yourSheetName')
```

Comment: What if both X and Y columns are in the same excel or csv file which is the case in my situation? I'v got both columns in the same file and want to add those two columns as an array list of values. Thanks!

Comment: After reading your file, you can easily take a column as a list in your code. Just look for it in pandas documentation.